# Continuous map $S^1\to S^1$ with $|$fiber$|$ constant is a covering map

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Recall that for any positive integer $n$, the map $S^1\to S^1$, $z\mapsto z^n$ is a degree $n$ covering map. I am considering the following possible generalization: suppose that a continuous map $f:S^1\to S^1$ satisfies $|f^{-1}(z)|=n$ for all $z\in S^1$. Then is it true that $f$ is a covering map (necessarily of degree $n$)? I cannot find a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Intuitively, flatten the circle and wrap it around itself once so that it just barely touches. The preimage of every point with have cardinality $2$. If I didn't make a mistake, this map should do the trick:

$$e^{i\theta}\mapsto e^{2i|\theta|}\text{ for }\theta\in [-\pi, \pi].$$